# Find $\sum_{k=0}^6 \operatorname{Re}(Z_k)$ and $\sum_{k=0}^6\operatorname{Im}(Z_k)$ .If the Equation $(Z+1)^7=Z^7$ has roots$Z_0,Z_2...Z_6$.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, roots, roots-of-unity

> Find $\sum_{k=0}^6 \operatorname{Re}(Z_k)$ and  $\sum_{k=0}^6 \operatorname{Im}(Z_k)$. If the equation $(Z+1)^7=Z^7$ has roots$Z_0,Z_2...Z_6$.

**My approach:**

$(\frac{Z+1}{Z})^7=1$

$(\frac{Z+1}{Z})^7=\cos(2k\pi)+i\sin(2k\pi)$

Then by De Moivre's Theorem

$(\frac{Z+1}{Z})=\cos(\frac{2k\pi}{7})+i\cdot\sin(\frac{2k\pi}{7})$

$1+\frac{1}{Z}=\cos(\frac{2k\pi}{7})+i\cdot\sin(\frac{2k\pi}{7})$

$\frac{1}{Z}=-1+\cos(\frac{2k\pi}{7})+i\cdot\sin(\frac{2k\pi}{7})$

$\frac{1}{Z}=-2sin^2(\frac{k\pi}{7})+i\cdot 2sin(\frac{k\pi}{7})\cdot\cos(\frac{k\pi}{7})$

$\frac{1}{Z}=-2i\sin(\frac{k\pi}{7})+i\cdot 2\sin(\frac{k\pi}{7})\cdot\cos(\frac{k\pi}{7})$

$\frac{1}{Z}=-2i\cdot\sin(\frac{k\pi}{7})(\cos(\frac{k\pi}{7})+\cdot i\sin(\frac{k\pi}{7}))$

$Z=\frac{(-1+i\cot(\frac{k\pi}{7}))}{2}=\frac{-1}{2}+\frac{i\cot(\frac{k\pi}{7})}{2}$

Which will have $7$ roots for $k=0,1,2,...6$

If I Sum all roots that must be not defined because $cot0$ is not defined.

But according to me $\sum_{k=0}^6 \operatorname{Re}(Z_k)$ must be $\frac{-7}{2}$ and $\sum_{k=0}^6\operatorname{Im}(Z_k)$ must be not defined.

Am i correct?

**My second Approach:**

Using binomial Expansion I am getting $0\cdot Z^7+7Z^6+...+1=0$

By Vieta's formula $\frac{7}{0}$ which is not defined.
Also because highest degree term is getting cancelled so one root will approach to infinity.

Am I making any mistake.
Is any other way to solve this problem?

Comment: $(Z+1)^7 -Z^7$  is a polynomial of degree *six,* it cannot have seven roots $Z_0, Z_1, \ldots, Z_6$.

Comment: what about the question find equation of line which are unit distance from point $(1,1)$ and passing through origin. And when we solve using distance formula we get two value of slope one being infinite and other being zero. SO there are two lines $x$-axis and $y$axis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Regarding your second approach: the given equation expands into the degree-$6$ polynomial $$7 Z^6 + 21 Z^5 + 35 Z^4 + 35 Z^3 + 21 Z^2 + 7 Z + 1 = 0,$$ so, Vieta's formula gives the sum of its six—not seven—roots as $-\frac{21}7=-3.$
2. As for your first approach, the mistake was neglecting to exclude $k=0$ at the step immediately preceding “Then by De Moivre's Theorem” (by the way, this isn't accurate: De Moivre's theorem, for technical reasons, applies only for integer powers, not $\frac17$). This is necessary because the preceding line $$\left(\frac{Z+1}{Z}\right)^7=1$$ necessitates that $Z\neq1.$

   Here's my full answer:
   $$(Z+1)^7=Z^7\\ \left(1+\frac1Z\right)^7=1\\
   Z=\left(e^\frac{i2n\pi}7-1\right)^{-1}\quad
   \left(n\notin7\mathbb Z\right)\\
   =\left(\cos\left(\frac{2n\pi}7\right)-1+i\sin\left(\frac{2n\pi}7\right)\right)^{-1}\\
   =\frac{\cos\left(\frac{2n\pi}7\right)-1-i\sin\left(\frac{2n\pi}7\right)}{2-2\cos\left(\frac{2n\pi}7\right)}\\
   =-\frac12+i\frac{\sin\left(\frac{2n\pi}7\right)}{2\left(\cos\left(\frac{2n\pi}7\right)-1\right)}\\
   =-\frac12-i\frac12\cot\left(\frac{2n\pi}7\right).$$
   Therefore, $$\sum_{k=1}^6 \operatorname{Re}(Z_k)\\=6\left(-\frac12\right)\\=-3,$$
   and, since $\cot$ is an odd function, $$\sum_{k=1}^6
   \operatorname{Im}(Z_k)\\=\sum_{n\in\{\pm1,\pm2,\pm3\}}-\frac12\cot\left(\frac{2n\pi}7\right)\\=0.$$

Comment: I think Demovier Theorem apply for rational number.

Comment: @user710599 [De Moivre's theorem does not *generally* hold for non-integer powers.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula#Failure_for_non-integer_powers,_and_generalization) E.g., when $n=\frac12,$ the theorem doesn't apply here: $\displaystyle\: 1^\frac12=\left(\cos(2\pi)+i\sin(2\pi)\right)^{\frac12}\neq\cos(\pi)+i\sin(\pi)=-1.$ In your case, it worked because you had already specified $1$ in its full generality as $e^{i\,2k\pi}.$

Comment: https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Precalculus/Book%3A_Trigonometry_(Sundstrom_and_Schlicker)/05%3A_Complex_Numbers_and_Polar_Coordinates/5.03%3A_DeMoivres_Theorem_and_Powers_of_Complex_Numbers

Comment: @user710599 In plain English: de Moivre’s theorem *only* claims to **always** work for integer powers.
$$$$ Sure, its scope can be *extended* to fractional powers *if the arguments are written in general form* — but the theorem as it is does not claim to (always) work for fractional powers, and, indeed fails for $n=\frac12$ in my above counterexample.

Comment: but square roots of unity are two 1 and -1

Comment: @user710599 Yes, and my above counterexample gives an instance where trying to apply De Moivre’s to a non-integer power results in a contradiction of this fact. You see the blue link in my first comment? It leads to a section titled “Failure of De Moivre’s theorem for non-integer powers”; perhaps click on it.  Anyway, this issue (De Moivre) is merely tangential to both your original question and the main thrust of my posted answer addressing the main error in each of your two approaches.